# "Settings" option not appearing. After upgrading Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from 18.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, system-settings, display-manager

I upgraded  my Ubuntu version to 20.04, Focal Fossa, by using the Ubuntu "Software & Update" feature. After completing upgrading it looks fine. But when I need to change display settings, right-clicking the settings option does not work, I have no idea why.  Also, I noticed that, when it was upgrading, some packages were removed. Please help me to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-installing `gnome-control-center`:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```

Then, the commands for opening Settings/Display Settings would be, respectively:

```
gnome-control-center

gnome-control-center display
```

There you are.  Hope it helps!